# Receiving a single line of text from servlet using XMLHttp request

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send an XMLHttp request from a JSP to a servlet and display a message in alert() received from server. But I am basically receiving the `<script> <script/>` part with some html tag.

Here is my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>

 <script>
    var xmlHttp;

    function createXMLHttpRequest() {
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    }
   function startRequest() {
   createXMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
   xmlHttp.open("post", "testServlet", true);
   // var msg="Hello world";
   xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
   function handleStateChange(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
      if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
        alert("The server replied with: " +xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
    }
   }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form action="#">
<input type="button" value="Press ME!!"
 onclick="startRequest();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my servlet code:

```
 package pk1;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  @WebServlet("/testServlet")
  public class testServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public testServlet() {
     super();
    }


protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,                            

     HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {

    test(response);
 }


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,   

    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    test(response);
}

public void test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

     String data = "This is a response from testServlet";
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.write(data);

    out.flush();
    out.close();

    }

}
```

Since I am using Tomcat7 I guess I don't need to specify URL mapping? so what am I doing wrong here? kindly let me know.

Comment: Which method you want to use for your ajax call POST/GET

Comment: for now any of post/get is fine.Here I am using post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line

```
function startRequest() {
   createXMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
   xmlHttp.open("post", "testServlet", true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');   // add here 
   xmlHttp.send(null);
```

And also in your servlet first try with doPost,

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,   

    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    
     out.print("Hi ");    
}
```

Hope it helps! notify if it works

Comment: Yes I did.Thanks for notifying the mistake..now I get the alert text but the responseText is showing nothing here.By the way,to check if my servlet is really been accessed I put system.out.println("some txe"); in my doGet/doPost method but when I press the button I dont see any printed message on the console.So is my sevelt not being accessed?could this be my problem?

Comment: try <form action="servlet">

Comment: I did but doesnt change anything.

Comment: @user3148750 I have updated my answer , Pls try this

Comment: @san krish  I edited as you mentioned.But now I don't get the alert message.Something wrong with responseText?isnt it receiving the response( HI in my case)?

Comment: I figured out my problem.I had some problem in the web-xml.Now it works thanks for the help guys!!cheers!!